# Android Firebase Notification with image not working

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement a class that receives a firebase notification and, if "image" key exists,  also show it. It receives the notification as expected but with no image. I tried to output in console if the key "image" exists or not but nothing is outputted. I would be glad if someone can help.

The relevant part of the code is below:

```
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {
        "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"
    })]
    class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);
            SendNotifications(message.GetNotification().Body, message.GetNotification().Title,message.Data);

        }

        public void SendNotifications(string body, string Header, IDictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.favicon96_96);
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.favicon96_96));
            builder.SetContentTitle(Header);
            builder.SetContentText(body);
            builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true);

            if (data.ContainsKey("image"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is an image => "+data["image"]);
                var urlString = data["image"].ToString();
                var url = new URL(urlString);
                var connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
                connection.DoInput = true;
                connection.Connect();
                var input = connection.InputStream;
                var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(input);

                Notification.BigPictureStyle picStyle = new Notification.BigPictureStyle();
                picStyle.BigPicture(bitmap);
                picStyle.SetSummaryText(body);
                connection.Dispose();
                builder.SetStyle(picStyle);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("====== THERE ISNT ANY IMAGE ");
            }


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
```

Comment: Please try to set a local Image from Resource to ` Notification.BigPictureStyle` , If it could display correctly?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT just tried that but still same issue.

Comment: I test it with my project. It worked as normal. Please see this GIF(I used local Image to make a test).https://imgur.com/a/rC6dGhP, My `FirebaseMessagingService` code like this thread https://github.com/851265601/XAndroidFCMNotification/blob/master/FCMNotification/FCMNotifications/MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs

Comment: Did you try to use my code to load this local image? Is that worked?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I was unable to use the exactly same code because visual studio says that MainActivity does not contains a definition for property NOTIFICATION_ID and CHANNEL_ID. So I have altered NotificationID for 0 and removed Channel_ID.  No success, it keeps showing notification with no image. It's importante to say that I changed the image for an existent one.

Comment: Here is my demo https://github.com/851265601/XAndroidFCMNotification/tree/master/FCMNotification, you can copy the push notification code to make a test.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Only today I could download and test it. My apologies about the delay. It doesn't work. I copied everything exactly as in your code but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the image link in the data as below?

```
{
    "data": {
        "Image": "https://...."
    },
    "registration_ids": [
        "testtoken"
    ],
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: I'm using firebase's "Notification Composer". There is an option to include key/value pairs.

Comment: But I think there is other issue because even using an embeded image, it isn't showed.

Comment: the image link is http or https?